# SKSpriteNode does not render pdf image in asset catalog

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, skspritenode

As a test I have created a simple rectangle in affinity designer and exported it as a pdf.
I have included a screenshot of the file imported in asset catalog.
[image: image of button]

I have written de following code to show this "button".

```
override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
  let button = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed:"test")
  button.position = CGPoint(x: size.width * 0.5, y: size.height * 0.5)
  button.zPosition = 5
  self.addChild(button)
```

}

The button does not render when the app is run on the simulator. 
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in the pdf file. I got it to work using this [site](http://invisiblepixels.org/InvisibleWords/2014/11/02/vector-images-in-the-asset-catalogue/#vectorPDF)

Just in case someone else runs into the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem and very similar code. My question is: Do you use UIImageView in your project to present the button? In the article you refer to it is marked as a crucial point.
Well, I don't, I just present the scene in GameViewController by         skView.presentScene(scene) where scene is my GameScene scaled to aspect fill. My problem is that Xcode does not generate , I guess, different .png files from my .pdf as I always see the size of @1 when I build on different devices. I would be grateful, if you could tell me something more about how you present the button in your ViewController (if you use UIImageView or not), then I would know wether my problem originates from wrongly generated .pdf file or from a way I present it in a View Controller.

Comment: No I don't use uiImageView. However the important line is this

>If you can’t get it to work with your image, trying using this one. 

If it works, the problem lies with your vector image. The link “this one” links to a pdf that is known to work. Try that one. Then you know if the problem lies in the code or the vector image

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Well, I use "this" image, even my .pdfs work fine, but only if I do both crucial steps described, use pdf files and UIImageViews. When I write your code the image is rendered etc. but for different devices it does not change size, simply I see it @1x size as I put it in the casset. Anyway, good it works for you :)  thank you.